# rsync control server-side which files are getting synchronized

Tags: rsync

I am trying to backup full server. I do not want paths like `/proc` and `sys` for instance. Here is my `/etc/rsyncd.conf` file :

```
uid = 0
gid = 0
use chroot = true
read only = true
hosts allow = 10.11.12.13
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0

[slash]
  path = /
  files-from = <(find / -path /sys -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -print0)
```

When I launch the `find` command alone, I can list the files I want and it does not `print0` the contents of `/proc` nor `/sys`.

However, in the `rsyncd.conf` file, this instruction does not seem to be taken in account, and `rsync` tries to get the whole content of these folders which I don't want.

I could restrict the files on client side, but this is not what I want, I want this kind of restrictions being performed on server side.

Is this possible to do it inside this configuration file ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `rsyncd.conf` will expand the output from any sub-shell command like you imagined. Looking the source code for rsync didn't clear rsync expanding the list as you detailed in your question. Reading the manual only makes it clear that it is expecting a string with `paths`.

In my opinion your best bet would be to have a cronjob generating the files list locally and to have rsync just reading that file.

I'd even suggest you to use a better suited backup solution, like bareos or bacula, instead of rsync.